# Is there anything like GCM for offline communication?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Seems like GCM for Android only works if there is internet. Wondering whether there are any other methods (maybe via text/call, etc) that could trigger a background service which would send back user's location (via text, etc. or maybe keep it until connection is present)?

My two concerns are:

1. How much can I do without the user doing anything (or even knowing it's happening... assuming they downloaded the app already and gave appropriate permissions)?
2. How would I send the data back? (if via text, Reason #1 seems to be a bigger matter)

Comment: there is a way. Network provider will know the location of devices based on AGPS-enabled base station. However, normally these information will not release to public due to privacy matters. All you need is cellphone signal, no Internet is required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution but it is costly,

- Create Broradcast Receiver that listen for incoming SMS.
- In any sms with start some predefined word like "START_SERVICE" is arrived then fire the broadcast and start the service you want.
- You may use normal SMS scheme or any bulk sms kind of service.

The above scenario doesn't require any INTERNET connection at all.

Comment: SMS will cost a lot $.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, that's why I mentioned it in my first line. :) ; Also read the third point.

Comment: that's sounds pretty cool. What about sending back the data? (Location object... maybe just lat/lon if via text). Is it possible to send a text without the user's permission or knowing?

Comment: No, Its not possible unless any app is installed which does this operation without user's interaction. However whenever any SMS will be send user may know it as his/her amount will get reduced. You may call any GPRS service which perform the same thing for you without any user interaction.